# How To Write a Log File in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have Written this code for log file.but I don't know hot to use it in my project.

this is my CreateLogFile.cs

```
class CreateLogFiles
{
    private string sLogFormat;
    private string sErrorTime;
    public CreateLogFiles()
    {
        //sLogFormat used to create log files format :
        // dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM ==> Log Message
        sLogFormat = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString() + "" +
            DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString() + "==>";

        //this variable used to create log filename format "
        //for example filename : ErrorLogYYYYMMDD
        string sYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        string sMonth = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
        string sDay = DateTime.Now.Day.ToString();
        sErrorTime = sYear + sMonth + sDay;
    }
    public void Info(string sPathName, string sInfoMsg)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sPathName + sInfoTime, true);
        sw.WriteLine(sLogFormat, sInfoMsg);
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();
    }
}
```

I want to use it in my controller code,but it doesn't show the massage :

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "LastName,FirstMidName,EnrollmentDate")] Student student)
    {
        cl.Info(Server.MapPath("/Log/LogFile.txt"),"Success");
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Students.Add(student);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View(student);
    }
```

Comment: Why not use something like Log4Net? There are plenty of tutorials in getting started and usage etc. and they do a much better job than you will of managing files etc. ;)
If you have to use your own class, please post an example of what you've tried in order to get this working as you dont seem to instantiate CreateLogFiles anywhere in your controller

Comment: @LDJ I was change my code.And this time it doesn't show the message